# Steam API: Is it possible to get tradable restriction property in seconds?

Tags: node.js, json, steam-web-api

Right now as I'm working on a project that uses the Steam API to fetch a user's inventory per game. The call goes through with no errors and the data is sent back as expected (JSON format).

I have noticed the **market_tradable_restriction** property is part of each asset (*whether the **tradable** property is set to true(1) or false(0)*), and it contains an integer representing the trade restriction in days (ex. 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 30, 60..).

What I'm curious about is whether the Steam API provides any property/function/ability to express **market_tradable_restriction** in seconds/minutes/anything that i can turn into a **DD HH MM** Calendar format

I've  tried searching the Steam API for answers, but to little fruition.
To be completely honest, i have not searched much, but i always tend to ask questions while searching. Who knows, maybe (most likely) someone already has the answers i seek.